# ConstraintLayout, 0dp in layout_height, but view is moved far left?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I'm trying to set the height of a custom view so it is equal to its parent.

The following layout does correctly sets the height of the custom view to its parent (i've logged the calls to OnMeasure). But the contraint layout fails to position the view correctly. As soon as layout_height is set to 0dp, the view is moved far left (including in the android studio designer).

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        />

    <View
        android:background="#ff0000"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

If i set this height to 10dp the view appears.

It seems the ContraintLayout is hiding the view because it has 0dp in one of its properties. How is this possible ?

The [doc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/constraint/ConstraintLayout.html) explains that is should switch to MATCH_CONSTRAINT instead.

What am i doing wrong ?

Comment: You have it set to app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf you probably meant app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf

Comment: See, it was a silly mistake.

Comment: Add it as answer so i can vote :) BenP is trying to get the points :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf. You probably meant app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf

Answer (score 1):

Your view is appearing off-screen because you have specified `constraintRight_toLeftOf` instead of `constraintRight_toRightOf`.